# blackberry efficient scrollable horizontal lists

Tags: blackberry

I have a group of images which I would like to display in a horizontal list, the size of the list will vary depending on what option a user selects.
However, I am unsure of the best way to implement a list if I have a large number of images to supply to a it, therefore generating many fields that need to be drawn.

My idea to make the list efficient:
-Store n images in a circular array. 
-Display  the first 3 images in3 views on the Screen that are visible to the user (e.g. <-- img1   img2   img3 -->)
-Keep a record of what's on display..
-When a user scrolls left or right the next/previous image in the array is displayed.
E.g scrolling right once will give me (   <--  img2  img3 img4 --> )
E.g scrolling left 3 times from the above point will give me  ( < -- img(n-1)  img(n)  img1 --> )
and so on...

What would be the best way to do the above, or are there any better ways?
I would be grateful if someone could direct me to the relevant documentation, api methods that I should use as well.
Is there already a method in the api that can recycle views in a similar fashion...?

I'm using ver v5.0.

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried PictureScrollField

> A slider component that draws a row of
>   images which can be scrolled from
>   side-to-side using the track-ball or
>   touch gestures. The images slide
>   horizontally to align the focus image
>   in a vertically centered position. The
>   images decelerate as they approach
>   their new position to give an animated
>   effect. There are also several
>   configurable effects to highlight the
>   focus image.
>
> All images are allocated the same
>   amount of space on slider (as defined
>   by the constructor's imageWidth and
>   imageHeight parameters). Images can
>   differ from that size in which case
>   the scroll field behaves as follows:
>
> Images are NOT resized.  If they are
>   larger than the allocated drawing area
>   they are center aligned and cropped to
>   fit the allocated area.  If they are
>   smaller than the allocated drawing
>   area they are center aligned in the
>   allocated area.
>
> Since: BlackBerry API 5.0.0